# Wait Timeout setting of mysql and JDBC error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I see the following error in the log:

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection
>   closed.Connection was implicitly
>   closed by the driver.

I have reduced the wait_timeout in my.cnf to 60
Should I set the default value for this parameter?
I am told my Java Programmers that this may be one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a same exception as yours, I think you did some operations after you closed the connection.For example:

```
{
```

try{
Connecton conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);

....

....

....

conn.close();

conn.commit();//Any operations on conn after conn.close() will throw //com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

}catch(Exception e){

...

}finally{

...

}

}

The example shows how the exception come out.I think you did something like it does.

Comment: I will like to know if I should increase wait_timeout to default 28800 to be on safer side.